# How to get the owner of a page

Tags: php, api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm thinking of writing a contact form but I need to get the owner of the form, not the person who filled out the form. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the owners of a page, query the `page_admin` [FQL table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/page/)

`fql?q=SELECT uid FROM page_admin WHERE page_id=PAGEID`

Comment: You get page id from your `signed_request` parameter. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ for info

Comment: there is no pageid in signed_requed

Comment: OK I got the PAGE ID. Can you give a example code to call FQL

Comment: $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
       
        $page_id = $signed_request['page']['id'];
      // print_r($signed_request );

      $fql    = "SELECT uid from page_admin WHERE page_id = '" . $page_id . "'";

$param  =   array(
 'method'    => 'fql.query',
 'query'     => $fql
);
$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);

      print_r ($fqlResult);

Comment: I see you found the page id and how to get the admin id.  You should look closer at all of the properties of the signed request as there **might** be something in there that's usable for your situation.

Comment: Then the user access token you're using doesn't have the correct permissions and/or the user is not one of the admins of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for here, but for instance if a user who's the owner of the form is logged in where the form is being used, then you can get his username from the $_SESSION array, given that you saved his username into that array upon the login process.